How to blur faces in captured video using Flutter
I would like to do the following in a Flutter app

Capture a video normally and store to local storage
Then post process this video, blurring all faces before uploading the video.

Best approach to achieve this?
MLKit?
OpenCV?
Any other techniques?
Thanks
I haven't tried anything yet, played around with face detection in preview, but I don't think I need face detection during capture, only need processing before upload

XFile videoFile = 'Your Video File';


Face Detection

Use a face detection library like google_ml_kit for face detection. This library can be used to detect faces in images, which can be applied to video frames.
google_ml_kit: ^0.7.2

import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';

Future<void> detectFaces(InputImage inputImage) async {
  final faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector();
  final faces = await faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);

  for (Face face in faces) {
    final Rect boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
    // Apply blur effect to the bounding box area
  }

  faceDetector.close();
}


Apply Blur Effect

You can use the image package for image processing:
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void blurFace(img.Image frame, Rect boundingBox) {
  int x = boundingBox.left.toInt();
  int y = boundingBox.top.toInt();
  int width = boundingBox.width.toInt();
  int height = boundingBox.height.toInt();

  img.copyInto(
    frame,
    img.blurGaussian(img.copyCrop(frame, x, y, width, height), 10),
    dstX: x,
    dstY: y,
  );
}

Extract frames from the video, process each frame to blur detected faces, and reassemble the frames into a video

So, given that I have an existing video, with audio, what library can be used to assemble the new face blurred frames and use the existing audio?
